# How to check if a dojo combobox drop down list is revealed up or down?

Tags: combobox, popup, dojo

I'm trying to detect the direction a djitComboBoxMenuPopup is opening, up or down. My goal is to have a different style applied when it expands up, rather than down. Is there any built in way to detect this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a function provided to do this, but you could "hack" your own by checking the positioning of the two elements client side. To do this use each the `comboBox.domNode.getBoundingClientRect().top` and `comboBox.dropDown.domNode.getBoundingClientRect().top`

then use those values in an if to determine which is rendered above which.

Example:

```
var comboTop = comboBox.domNode.getBoundingClientRect().top;
var dropDownTop = comboBox.dropDown.domNode.getBoundingClientRect().top;

if( dropDownTop < comboTop ){
    //Drop down is above combo
} else {
    //Drop down is below combo    
}
```

support for `getBoundingClientRect()` may vary from browser to browser, but my understanding is that it's supported by all modern browser versions.